# Date Validation in Angular 2

Tags: angular

**This is my method date validation**

```
  //Validation Date
  validateDate(inputDate: Date, dateNow: Date) {
    if (inputDate <= dateNow) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**This is my method formSubmit when the submit form,and i call the method validate date in this method**

```
  //When Submit Form
  formSubmits() {
    this.processValidation = true;
    let workorderss = this.workorderForm.value;

    let inputDate = new Date(workorderss.dueDate);
    let dateNow = new Date(Date.now());

    //Validation Failed
    if (this.workorderForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.validateDate(inputDate, dateNow) == false) {
      alert("Date Must Now!")
      return;
    }

    //Form is Valid
    this.preProcessConfigurations();

    workorderss.inspectors = { 'id': workorderss.inspectors };
    workorderss.questioners = { 'id': workorderss.questioners, 'questionerDetails': [] };
    this.workorderService.getAllWorkOrder()
      .subscribe(workorders => {
        this.workorderService.createWorkOrder(workorderss)
          .subscribe(successCode => {
            this.statuscode = successCode;
            this.workorderForm.reset();
            alert("Create WorkOrder Success");
            this.locations.back();
          },
          errorCode => alert("Code is Already Exist")
          );

      });

  }
```

But the problem is,when i choose the date now,example: "date now is 17 May 2018,and i choose date 17 may 2018" i get the date is failed validation...how to set validation date when i choose the date now is not failed and when i set before date now is failed...in this validate i realize i set the **date <= dateNow** but i don't know the validation to set when i choose dateNow not failed.

Answer (score 0):

change `<=` to just `<`

so, your new validation function would be

```
  validateDate(inputDate: Date, dateNow: Date) {
    if (inputDate < dateNow) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```